# Rails 4: how can I merge scope from an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a simple question.

I have a couple of models associated:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ContentSharable
 scope :published, -> { where(visible: true).where 'published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now }
end

class ContentShare < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sharable, polymorphic: true
  scope :for_feed, -> { where.not(image: nil) }
end
```

I need that `ContentShare.for_feed` returns to me all the record where `image is not null` and where the associated `sharable` is `published`. How can I merge the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scoped` method:

`relation = ContentShare.for_feed.scoped.merge(Video.published)`

See the documentation for more details:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped

Comment: I tried but ContentShare is a Polymorfic association, I have "Video", Gallery and other classes...